# How to manage unique ID's for altered polygon

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, gis-principle

I'm working with administrative boundary polygons and am wondering when to keep the existing unique ID, and when to assign a new unique ID to a polygon. For example, if District A merges with District B and is still called District A, do I keep the original ID for District A, or create a new ID? What about when District A keeps the same geometry, but is renamed to District B? Or when the boundaries are slightly changed? Is there a standard way to manage unique ID's?